# Functions which returns numeric values from array

Tags: php, arrays

I have an array which contains string as well as numeric values, does anyone know of a PHP function which would return only the numeric values when passed such a parameter accordingly?

Comment: What did you try? Did you **at least** read the docs?

Answer (score 2):

[`array_filter`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-filter.php) sounds like the function which you are looking for. You can pass it an array and a "callback" function to run on each element. Entries for which the callback returns a [`FALSE`-like](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.boolean.php) value will be removed. So, combined with, for example, [`is_numeric`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.is-numeric.php), all non-numeric values would be removed from the array.

Example:

```
$foo = array('a', 'b', '2', '3.14', 'd');
$bar = array_filter($foo, 'is_numeric');
var_dump($bar);

# => array(2) {
#      [2] =>
#      string(1) "2"
#      [3] =>
#      string(4) "3.14"
#    }
```

Similarly, you could try with the callbacks: [`is_int`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.is-int.php), [`is_float`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.is-float.php), etc.

Comment: Wow, I like the use of `array_filter()`. I think I would've done it in a loop. But this is really ingenious.